# Using variables from another python file into my current file

Tags: python, file, input, import

I am trying to take a string variable from a python file and use it in another python file. It looks like it does not recognize the newly imported variable even if I can print it.

I am running python 3.6.4. An if I write my string by hand the code runs and it does not go into the exception.

variable_name.py

```
first='equilibrium'
```

file2.py

```
import variable_name

print(variable_name.first)

try:
    input.variable_name.first.get()
    variable_name.first = input.variable_name.first
except:
    print("The equilibrium IDS is absent from the input datafile")
    print("----> Aborted.")
    exit()
```

If I try to put by hand 'equilibrium' the code does not go into the exception. But if I read it from the variable_name.py it gives me the exception.

Comment: `input.variable_name.first.get()` - what exactly are you trying to do here? Because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve 'equilibrium' tree structure and save it under a name that for consistency i also call it equilibrium

Comment: The code works when i run it with input.equilibrium.get() but i do not know why when I use the string 'equilibrium' saved in variable first from the first file it gives me an exception

Comment: is `input` an object defined elsewhere in your code? If so, you shouldn't do that because you're overwriting the built in `input` function. But more to the point here, you should share that, because it will be necessary to reproduce the particular issue you're seeing. And if, as it appears, the real issue is using a variable as a property name, look up [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

Comment: The problem is that my code is on a cluster and there are several modules running including the 'input' definition so you can not reproduce the error.  My problem is not with the code itself because as I said, it runs perfectly fine when I put 'equilibrium' directly into the second file. My overall purpose is to make another simple python file that has a list of variables. The values for the variables such as 'first='equilibrium'' to be replaced by the user to make it easier to run the main code which has about 600 lines.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many other modules you have, `input` will only be affected if you import `input` from one of those other modules (or if, God forbid, you have `from some_module import *` and `some_module` defines `input`). In any case, you won't get much help here if you can't strip the code back to an example which reproduces the problem. Although, as I alluded to above, it sounds like `getattr(input, variable_name.first).get()` will do as you want, did you try it?

Comment: Tried that, it does not work, for example I have another piece of code that does input.core_profiles.get() so by modifying first in variable_name. to check for core_profiles or for equilibrium. I understand why it does not work but I do not know a solution for this. I do not want to make them take arguments when I run the code, there are way too many for that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confusing about, values and variables? When you assign a value as string, its not considered as variable name, compiler will not understand as you understand.
For instance you are trying to achieve below :

```
hello = 1
x = 'hello'
print (x)
```

You expecting result as `1` not ofcourse it will write `hello` here.

What you can do here is

variable_name.py

```
equilibrium = 'smth'
```

file2.py

```
import variable_name

print(variable_name.equilibrium)
try:
    input.variable_name.equilibrium.get()
    variable_name.equilibrium = input.variable_name.equilibrium
except:
    print("The equilibrium IDS is absent from the input datafile")
    print("----> Aborted.")
    exit()
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the whole point for creating the variable_name file was so the user can put any IDS name instead of equilibrium, for instance core_profiles.

Comment: ok you should accept that user cannot change variable name by design, it might only change values of variables. Variable names should be commanded by hardcoder (you). Just think more, you will find better way to express your code to end user.

Or you can put readme in variable_name.py that user can define its own variables with values and you can `setattr` the variables and use in your code.